# Possible to continue using iMac keyboard on iMac, when another computer connects in Target Display Mode?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, imac, target-display

I have a MacBook Pro which I use to connect to my iMac, using Target Display Mode (TDM) via Thunderbolt.

Furthermore, I've got a secondary screen connected to my iMac via an DVI cable.

When I invoke TDM, my MacBook will take control of its own screen and the iMac screen.

But the *2nd screen* is still displaying my iMac.

What I would like to do here, is *continue to use my iMac, only on the 2nd screen*, while the MacBook gets to control my iMac screen.

The *mouse* of the iMac still works on my *2nd screen*. But the iMac ***keyboard*** does not work. For some reason, the only character I can type with it is <kbd>a</kbd>.

Question: Is there a way to get the iMac keyboard working in this setup?

---

This is kind of what my setup looks like (not my image, but pretend it’s a MacBook Pro, iMac and secondary screen):

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use the second screen for your MacBook?

Comment: @IronCraftMan That's what I'm doing while we try to figure out the answer to the question in the OP :)